# Apache restart error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin, apache2

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04 from [here](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

After i installed apache2 i run the below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and i got the below errors, anyway how to solve this error and install phpmyadmin on ubuntu

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                 apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

And when i tried `localhost/phpmyadmin` from browser its showing `Welcome to nginx!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Nginx webserver running on probably the same port Apache is trying to bind to.
I don't know who is using this Nginx webserver, but you can stop it with:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Then try starting Apache again.

To see who is using which ports:

```
sudo netstat -nptul
```

Comment: k tried same as above, and still after running the apache server again it showing the same error

Comment: does the netstat command tell you if there is still something running on port 80?

Comment: i got this line for port when i ran netstat 80 "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1573/nginx: worker"

Comment: Could you try `sudo /usr/bin/nginx -s stop`

Comment: Did you btw. installed this nginx server? Some other tool may be using it.

Comment: if i type above its showing sudo: /usr/bin/nginx: command not found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34994/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-rickya)

Comment: ah, sbin: `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s stop`

Comment: result nginx: [alert] kill(1572, 15) failed (3: No such process)

Comment: if u dont mind can we continue this in chat ? here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34994/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-rickya

Answer (score 0):

You have a nginx webserver running that listens to port 80, so Apache can't bind to that port. You have to shut nginx down first using something like

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```